# Laravel parent / child relationship on the same model

Tags: php, laravel

### The Setup And Dummy Data

I have a simple model called Category, which has the following schema:

```
|----------------------------------------------|
| cat_id   | cat_name    | parent_id           |
|----------------------------------------------|
|   1      | Home        |   0                 |
|----------------------------------------------|
|   2      | Products    |   1                 |
|----------------------------------------------| 
|   3      | Services    |   1                 |
|----------------------------------------------|
|   4      | Product A   |   2                 |
|----------------------------------------------|
|   5      | Product B   |   2                 |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

### The Desired Output

So you can see that we would get a very straight forward hierarchy as follows:

```
Home
  - Products
      - Product A
      - Product B
  - Services
```

### The Issue

I'm trying to map this relationship in Laravel 4.2, so that I can query a model and get its parent (it will always have a parent), and child categories if they exist.

I've defined the relationship in the Category model using:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Category', 'parent_id', 'cat_id');
}
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'parent_id');
}
```

### The Problem

I can get the parent name working, using

```
$category = Category::findOrFail($id);
return $category->parent->cat_name;
```

However, I don't understand how to get the child objects.

I've tried:

```
$category = Category::findOrFail($id);
$children = $category->children();
```

But when I dd($children) it doesn't output what I'd expect.

Comment: What is the output of $children?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Calling the relationship function (`->children()`) will return an instance of the relation class. You either need to call then `get()` or just use the property:

```
$children = $category->children()->get();
// or
$children = $category->children;
```

### Further explanation

Actually `children()` and `children` are something pretty different. `children()` just calls the method you defined for your relationship. The method returns an object of `HasMany`. You can use this to apply further query methods. For example:

```
$category->children()->orderBy('firstname')->get();
```

Now accessing the **property** `children` works differently. You never defined it, so Laravel does some magic in the background.

Let's have a look at `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`:

```
public function __get($key)
{
    return $this->getAttribute($key);
}
```

The `__get` function is called when you try to access a property on a PHP object that doesn't actually exist.

```
public function getAttribute($key)
{
    $inAttributes = array_key_exists($key, $this->attributes);

    // If the key references an attribute, we can just go ahead and return the
    // plain attribute value from the model. This allows every attribute to
    // be dynamically accessed through the _get method without accessors.
    if ($inAttributes || $this->hasGetMutator($key))
    {
        return $this->getAttributeValue($key);
    }

    // If the key already exists in the relationships array, it just means the
    // relationship has already been loaded, so we'll just return it out of
    // here because there is no need to query within the relations twice.
    if (array_key_exists($key, $this->relations))
    {
        return $this->relations[$key];
    }

    // If the "attribute" exists as a method on the model, we will just assume
    // it is a relationship and will load and return results from the query
    // and hydrate the relationship's value on the "relationships" array.
    $camelKey = camel_case($key);

    if (method_exists($this, $camelKey))
    {
        return $this->getRelationshipFromMethod($key, $camelKey);
    }
}
```

Then in `getAttribute` first is some code that checks for "normal" attributes and returns then. And finally, at the end of the method, if there's a relation method defined `getRelationshipFromMethod` is called.

It will then retrieve the result of the relationship and return that.

Comment: Ok, so the parenthesis on the children call are not required in this case. Somewhat confusing in an otherwise very beautiful framework, but that solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Set this in model and try :

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function grandchildren()
{
    return $this->children()->with('grandchildren');
}
```