# Merge posts of childrens category Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I created table to save posts and categories relation.

```
Schema::create('post__post_category_relations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsinged();
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsinged();
    });
```

This is category table:

```
Schema::create('post__categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('parent_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And I used relation eloquent to get all posts of category. This is Category Model:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post__post_category_relations', 'category_id');
}
public function children()
 {
   return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
 }
```

But a category might has childrens category. I want get all posts of childrens category when I show category parent. This is following my script:

```
public function show_category($slug){

    $category = $this->category->findBySlug($slug);

    $childrens = $category->children;

    $posts = ...?

    return view('post.category.show',compact('posts','category'));
}
```

I wan't merge posts of category parent and category chidren to variable $post. Anyone have good idea?

Sr, My english so bad. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel parent / child relationship on the same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816738/laravel-parent-child-relationship-on-the-same-model)

Comment: Thanks, I will see this post!

Comment: Show category table and model

Comment: Oh, this toturial tell about get children category, but I want get all posts of childrens to one variable.

Comment: Can you help me?