# Treeview with Laravel and Database

Tags: laravel, treeview

I found this function in Internet and it works.

In my App

```
public function childs(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Account','p_id');
}
```

In my route:

```
Route::get('tests', function(){
return App\Account::with('childs')
->where('p_id',0)
->get();
});
```

So if you have in the dabase a raw with `p_id = 0` and `id = 1` it return a category and if you have a raw with `p_id = 1` and `id = 2` that mean that the child of the categorie with `id = 1`.

Another example:: 
If you have a raw with `p_id = 6` and `id = 16` that mean that the child of the category with `id = 6`

Please who can explain to mean why  exactly it work like that ?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Relationship are not used to make relations between 1 model. You cannot make relation between `Account` and `Account`. An account does not has "hasMany" accounts.

You can have hasMany users for example.

```
public function childs(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\User','p_id');
}
```

Comment: Actually, you can call parent/children relation on model. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816738/laravel-parent-child-relationship-on-the-same-model) is explained too.